# How to properly send Event data from FullCalendarJs to livewire-ui/modal for editing?

Tags: fullcalendar, laravel-livewire, fullcalendar-6

When I click an event displayed in fullCalendarJs in order to edit it, I get a random event from the DB populated in the modal.

I use the "eventClick" from the fullCalendarJS :

[image: calendar blade]

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

Here is the data when clicking on an event :

[image: all data]

EventsEdit Component:

[image]

Comment: As per the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide, which you are encouraged to read before using the site, please don't post images of code, data or error messages. This information is text-based. Pasting it as graphics is very impractical as it can't be copied, searched, re-used in answers etc. It makes it difficult for those who might want to help you. Please [edit] your question to include the code as text and use the [formatting tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to present it nicely, so that it is usable for those who want to help you. Thanks